# Conditionally required in Zend Framework's 2 InputFilter

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I am making an application using Zend Framework 2. I am validating input using it's `InputFilter`. Is it possible, to make some `Input`s required conditionally? I mean I have code like that:

```
$filter = new \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter();
$factory = new \Zend\InputFilter\Factory();
$filter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name' => 'type',
    'required' => true
)));
$filter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name' => 'smth',
    'required' => true
)));
```

I want the field `something`, to be required, ONLY when `type` is equal `1`. Is there a built-in way to do that? Or should I just create custom validator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you may want to enable validation on empty/null values as of [Empty values passed to Zend framework 2 validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910431/empty-values-passed-to-zend-framework-2-validators)

You can use a callback input filter as in following example:

```php
$filter = new \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter();
$type   = new \Zend\InputFilter\Input('type');
$smth   = new \Zend\InputFilter\Input('smth');

$smth
    ->getValidatorChain()
    ->attach(new \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty(\Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::NULL))
    ->attach(new \Zend\Validator\Callback(function ($value) use ($type) {
        return $value || (1 != $type->getValue());
    }));

$filter->add($type);
$filter->add($smth);
```

This will basically work when the value `smth` is an empty string and the value for `type` is not `1`. If the value for `type` is `1`, then `smth` has to be different from an empty string.

Comment: Note that due to PHP's very loose way of checking interfaces, it is also possible to define a validator with a method `isValid($value, array $context = [])`. That way, `$context` can be used to enable/disable validation contextually.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't quite get the example by Ocramius to work, as $type->getValue was always NULL. I changed the code slightly to use $context and this did the trick for me:

```
$filter = new \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter();
$type   = new \Zend\InputFilter\Input('type');
$smth   = new \Zend\InputFilter\Input('smth');

$smth
    ->getValidatorChain()
    ->attach(new \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty(\Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::NULL))
    ->attach(new \Zend\Validator\Callback(function ($value, $context){
        return $value || (1 != $context['type']);
    }));

$filter->add($type);
$filter->add($smth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `setValidationGroup` for this.

Create your own `InputFilter` class where you set validation groups depending on the data that is set inside the inputfilter before executing the actual validation.

```
class MyInputFilter extends InputFilter
{
   setData($data){
       if(isset($data['type']) && $data['type'] === 1){
           // if we have type in data and value equals 1 we validate all fields including something
           setValidationGroup(InputFilterInterface::VALIDATE_ALL);
       }else{
           // in all other cases we only validate type field
           setValidationGroup(['type']);
       }
       parent::setData($data);
   }
}
```

This is just a simple example to show what is possible with `setValidatioGroup`, you can create your own combinations for setting validation groups after your specific needs.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately you'd have to set the required option based on your conditions like so:

```
$filter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name' => 'smth',
    'required' => (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == '1'),
)));
```

Comment: This is wrong. You are hereby setting values regarding a filter based on the request that has to be filtered: it's conceptually wrong.